# Number of garlands possible

Tags: combinatorics

There are $6n$ flower of one kind and $3$ of another kind. Show that number of different garlands made of using all these flowers is $3n^2+3n+1$.

My approach is divide garland in form of $a+b+a=6n+3$.
As it is circular but could not go ahead of it

Comment: The answer should be $6n^2 + 3n + 1$.